# Recovery of a corrupted database using only the .frm in Windows

Tags: mysql, windows

Is it possible to restore mysql database using only .frm files in Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly then probably not. According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/frm-file-format.html then the .frm file only stores the table structure; the actual data is in other files.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately it is impossible, maximum possible restore structure
InnoDB data stored in *.ibd files if set innodb_file_per_table=1 or in idbata1 if it 0.

for success repair even when innodb_file_per_table = 1, ibdata1 need as well.

if You have only from file = no chances restore data at all